# Firebase for Android - W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase (version 10.0.0) in my Android project and faced with the following problem with Firebase Database:

Precondition:
User is logged in via Firebase Auth with Google Account (*FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()* returns non null value).

1. In Main Activity's onCreate method I read some value from Firebase Database:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child(NODE_USERS).child(user.getUid()).child(NODE_DICTIONARY_VERSION)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);`

2. It works fine. But after some time the method described above goes to some kind of endless loop (no errors, no *onCancelled* call in *ValueEventListener*). Also the following message appears in log:

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. 
This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. 
Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key. 
You can re-download google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/
```

After that all other calls to Firebase Database (read, write, remove, etc) also don't work.

To fix this I tried to

1. do silent login on application startup before accessing Firebase Database:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(...);
```

2. reconnect with Firebase Database:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
```

As a result, the problem with Firebase Database appears not so often and at least after a day has passed. Also the problem is disappeared for a some time if to restart the whole application (without these fixes the problem reproduces every time, only re-login helps).

Anyway, the problem still exists and application restart is a very bad solution :)

Any idea how to fix this problem? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

The full Firebase log:

```
12-19 13:03:40.544  D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( HbY7R8FPR6QwgstQd3wmypI2nwJ2 ).
12-19 13:03:40.546  D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
12-19 13:03:40.546  D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
12-19 13:03:40.546  D/RepoOperation: Auth token changed, triggering auth token refresh
12-19 13:03:40.602  D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( HbY7R8FPR6QwgstQd3wmypI2nwJ2 ).
12-19 13:03:40.613  D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
12-19 13:03:40.613  D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
12-19 13:03:40.613  D/RepoOperation: Auth token changed, triggering auth token refresh
12-19 13:03:43.832  V/FA: Session started, time: 176462962
12-19 13:03:43.853  I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-19 13:03:43.858  D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity, _si=3824046701607023337}]
12-19 13:03:43.885  V/FA: Using measurement service
12-19 13:03:43.885  V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-19 13:03:43.909  D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-19 13:03:43.910  V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
12-19 13:03:44.139  W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.
12-19 13:03:45.985  W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.
12-19 13:03:48.945  V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

P.S. It looks like the problem appears on my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1) only. There is no such problem with Sony Xperia V (Android 4.3).

P.P.S. I also tried to build debug and release apks and to add "Editor" role to all autogenerated service accounts in google cloud console - it does not help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found how to fix the problem thanks to the Firebase support engineers! :)

The trick is to wait for getting *FirebaseAuth* from *FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener* (instead of getting it directly from the *FirebaseAuth.getInstance()*) prior to accessing Firebase Database **at application startup**: it looks like Firebase needs some time to initialize/renew user authentication.

So, the following code doesn't work correctly:

```
// Main Activity
protected void onCreate(...) {
   if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
      // accessing Firebase Database
   }
}
```

It must be like the this:

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
    //...
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
               // accessing Firebase Database
            }
        }
    };
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alexander's answer did not work for me..

Seems that clearing all *Google Play services* storage solves the problem **Settings => Apps => Google Play services => Storage => MANAGE STORAGE => CLEAR ALL DATA**, this issue probably needs to be fixed by Firebase or Google.

Comment: This solved my issue too, but I wonder if this could affect my user's performance. Do you have any idea if we could get around this programmatically, without requiring them to clear data manually?

Comment: I am also searching for this. This will happen rarely but it has to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error but what created is that i switched the google-service.json from old project to new but my app was still connecting to the old one so i did this and it solved it maybe there was some cache problem in android studio.

Steps:

1. Invalidating the cache and restart
2. clean project
3. rebuild project

hope it helps you