# Firebase realtime database does not work when the app is turned back on after the backgroud

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a big problem with Firebase. I implemented long ago in my app service Realtime Firebase database. Everything worked properly. For several weeks, however, I had some problems. When the app is in the backgroud and stays there for some time, Firebase goes offline and realtime database service is not working properly. I looked up on the web and saw that there were many problems with this thing, but I have not found a solution for me. Also I get the following error:

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.
```

Of course I tried to re-download the json file and I also checked all the keys. is a bug in the database

This makes my application unusable. I tried to create a service account by following this https://itayhauptman.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/firebase-firebase-warning-provided-authentication-credentials-are-invalid-this-usually-indicates-your-firebaseapp-instance-was-not-initialized-correctly/ guide,

I tried the solzuione suggested in this [Firebase for Android - W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221491/firebase-for-android-w-persistentconnection-pc-0-provided-authentication-cr]) question, I tried to streamline my code for errors. All these actions they do not resolve the problem. The last thing I'll do is create a new application in the Firebase console.

Before you do this, does anyone have any solution? 
I'm really desperate for this thing. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will not run your firebase app in the background all the time.
Android may kill your processes and services when it is sleeping or 'Dozing'.
You can wake your app up and do some sync if required using `AlarmManager`.

If your sync is some event triggered, setup **firebase cloud messaging** and perform the sync when a new message arrives.

Running your app in the background with a live connection to your backend is a very bad idea for Battery optimisation.

**EDIT:**

If you are running the background service in a different android process, you will have to initialise Firebase again by calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);` Either in the Application class or your service class; before any usages.

Comment: No, I do not want the Firebase service continues even in the backgroud. My Case Study is after the backgroud. When reactivated the application, the service is as if Firebase remain offline, and there is no way to reactivate it if you do not login again. Quidni I should just log in and every time you restart the application. I hope I explained

Comment: `FirebaseAuth` is supposed to persist the session and authentication. You should not need to login again.

Comment: @hulon i believe you are running your service in a different process. In Such a case you must initialise Firebase singleton again by calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);`