# W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. Firebase Database listener doesn't give any results (success or error)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Flow:
1. User clicks google login.
2. Selects google account and then I try to login to firebase using the credentials.
3. Firebase login is successful.
4. I try to access firebase database for pulling user stored info and that's where the magic happens.

!!!!!

The Database Listener keeps waiting for result. Nothing happens and after sometime I get this error in the log:

> W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are
>   invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not
>   initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has
>   the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download
>   google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.

Now the sad part is, this keeps happening on only a few phones and mostly in my debug phones. (I also tried release APKs in the same phones, it doesn't work). In other phones it runs well with no errors but in other phones in gives me the above mentioned error.

What am I supposed to do?

Extra Info:
Firebase SignIn Methods include: Google SignIn and Phone.

SignIn Activity Code:

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                if (result != null) {
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Google Sign In Successful");
                        if (result.getSignInAccount() != null) {
                            String googleAccountIDToken = result.getSignInAccount().getIdToken();
                            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(googleAccountIDToken);
                        } else {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Google Sign In Error");
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Google Sign-In Error. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Google Sign-In Error. Please try again!");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Google Sign-In Error. Please try again!");
                    try {
                        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(this);
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String googleAccountIDToken) {
    pd.show();
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleAccountIDToken, null);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Firebase Auth: Failed! ", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Firebase Auth: Successful!");
                    provider = Constants.PROVIDER_GOOGLE;
                }
            });
}

   private void firebaseAuthStateListener() {
        authStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Auth Called in Sign In Activity");
                getFirebaseToken();
            } else {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.i(TAG, "Auth User Null");
            }
        };
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    private void getFirebaseToken() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getFirebaseToken");
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            mAuth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            token = task.getResult().getToken();
                            saveToSharedPrefs();
                            attachCustomerProfileListener();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

  private void attachCustomerProfileListener() {
        Log.i(TAG, "attachCustomerProfileListener");
        fProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.FIREBASE_USERS).child(Constants.FIREBASE_CUSTOMERS).child(uid);
        fProfileListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String name = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                    Uri profilePic = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();
                    String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                    if (name != null) {
                        customerProfile.setName(name);
                    }
                    if (email != null) {
                        customerProfile.setEmail(email);
                    }
                    if (profilePic != null) {
                        customerProfile.setProfilePic(String.valueOf(profilePic));
                    }
                    customerProfile.setRegistrationLevel(Constants.RL_INITIAL);
                    customerProfile.setRideCount(0);
                    if (Objects.equals(provider, Constants.PROVIDER_GOOGLE)) {
                        providers.setGoogle(1);
                        providers.setFacebook(0);
                    } else {
                        providers.setFacebook(1);
                        providers.setGoogle(0);
                    }
                    customerProfile.setProviders(providers);
                    fProfile.setValue(customerProfile);
                    saveCustomerProfileToSavedPrefs(customerProfile);
                    saveBasicCustomer();
                } else {
                    customerProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomerProfileModel.class);
                    saveCustomerProfileToSavedPrefs(customerProfile);
                    nextActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        };
        fProfile.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(fProfileListener);
    }
```

LOG:

> D/$SgnInAct: Google Sign In Successful 08-12 22:37:09.876
>   14618-14618/ahija.com V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d4094af 08-12 22:37:09.876
>   14618-14618/ahija.com V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@26d0bc 08-12 22:37:09.880
>   14618-14618/ahija.com V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f8bcccb 08-12 22:37:09.880
>   14618-14618/ahija.com V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@6ee3ca8 08-12 22:37:09.901
>   14618-14641/ahija.com V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2222868 08-12
>   22:37:09.902 14618-15136/ahija.com D/AppTracker: App Event: start
>   08-12 22:37:09.903 14618-14641/ahija.com D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SignInHubActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-4110721026549782041,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignInActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4110721026549782042}] 08-12 22:37:11.304
>   14618-14737/ahija.com D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners
>   about user ( JFuRgcWzCeg1uV90SEGKJULEt3z1 ). 08-12 22:37:11.307
>   14618-14618/ahija.com D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>   08-12 22:37:11.309 14618-14618/ahija.com D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1
>   auth state listeners. 08-12 22:37:11.309 14618-14618/ahija.com
>   W/$SgnInAct: Firebase Auth: Successful! 08-12 22:37:14.934
>   14618-14641/ahija.com V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   08-12 22:37:32.997 14618-14631/ahija.com D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id
>   token listeners about user ( JFuRgcWzCeg1uV90SEGKJULEt3z1 ). 08-12
>   22:37:32.998 14618-14618/ahija.com D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state
>   listeners. 08-12 22:37:32.998 14618-14618/ahija.com D/FirebaseApp:
>   Notified 1 auth state listeners. 08-12 22:37:34.741
>   14618-14661/ahija.com W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided
>   authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your
>   FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your
>   google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key.
>   You can re-download google-services.json from
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/.

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing Firebase DB after AuthStateListener callback is called with non-null user result? I faced with the same problem sometime ago and described the solution in details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221491/firebase-for-android-w-persistentconnection-pc-0-provided-authentication-cr

Comment: The database call is done after authStateListener returns not null value of user. It only fails in few phones. In other phones, the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: I advice you to contact Firebase Support engineers via https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ - these guys are able to give you a response within a couple days.

Comment: And could you please tell which phones have the issue exactly? I will check my project too :)

Comment: OnePlus 3T, Moto G, OnePlus 5

Comment: Thanks! :) And good luck in solving the issue.